# I can do ssh from server to local pc but not from pc to server

Tags: ssh, scp

I can successfully ssh my local pc to remote server in a different network.
But reverse is not working (server to local pc).
I need to transfer the large files from server to my local pc and for that I wanted to use scp but before that I think first step is to get the ssh working.
please guide.

Comment: If you can ssh to the server from your PC, then you should be able to use something like `scp user@server:/path/to/bigfile somewhere/on/pc/` to transfer `bigfile` to your PC. There should be no need to connect from the server to the PC explicitly.

Comment: thanks , worked, i am using winscp to connet and transfer files to and from the server

Answer (score 2):

You do not need the server to ssh into your pc to send files from the server to your PC.  All you need to do is enter what @steeldriver said in his comment (which was to use `scp user@server:/path/to/bigfile somewhere/on/pc/`).

If you still need to ssh into your PC for some reason you could try making sure that `OpenSSH server` is installed/installing it.

(These instructions are for Windows, as I am presuming that's what your PC's operating system is by the fact you are using winscp)

Search for `Manage optional features` in the start menu, click on the top result -> select `Add a feature` at the top of the now open settings page --> type into the search box `OpenSSH Sever` --> select `OpenSSH Server` --> click `install (1)` at the bottom left.

After it has finished installing, you will need to open Powshell as Administrator, and type `Start-Service sshd` to start it, or `Set-Service -Name sshd -StartupType 'Automatic'` to make it startup automatically.

[For more information, you can look at Microsoft's tutorial here.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse)

This should allow you to be able to receive SSH connections on a Windows 10 PC.

Make sure that OpenSSH service is allowed through Windows Firewall.

Also, I just wanted to mention that you do not need to use a thirdparty software like winscp to use ssh/scp on Windows, as OpenSSH has been part of Windows for a couple of years now.  You can use ssh in the Windows cmd the same way you would in Linux Terminal. (E.g. `ssh <user>@<ip-address>`)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend usage of `rsync` over `scp`.

`rsync` gives much greater speed, and a resume capability in case the copy gets halted in between.

[image: Pic from stack overflow]
(source is cited in references)

### Usage:

```
# To copy files from a remote server to local machine
# =======> answer to your question <========================================
rsync -av username@remote.server.com:/path/to/resource /path/to/dst/on/local/machine

# To copy files from local machine to remote server
rsync -av /path/to/dst/on/local/machine username@remote.server.com:/path/to/resource 

# Go through manual pages for more information on rsync
man rsync
```

Also, if you are using a local ISP for internet, you might get a local ip address (something like 192.168.0.{0-254}), and the server has a fixed IP address (something like 100.172.34.26).

So the destination has a unique location, accessible from any ip, but the local machine IP address is masked (not exposed) to the entire internet, and that is the reason why you can't ssh from the remote server to your local machine.

### References:

- https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244585/how-does-scp-differ-from-rsync

Comment: Does this answer the question, and solve the problem?